# Nice, clean URL for my store

Tags: url, url-rewrite, server-setup, htaccess, .htaccess

I want that that, when I navigate to

`myStore.com`

the displayed contents are actually the ones of

`myStore.com/subdirectory`

but without changing the URL.

I tried different configurations of .htaccess but no one of them seems to work.

The reason why I need that is because I put my store in the server under www/subdirectory instead than in www directly. Which is the usual way to proceed? I did it this way because I want to keep my directories clean.

Any ideas on that? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using virtualhost configurations? This is a very common directory structure. Its common that we install Magento in a location other than www/html

Comment: Refer http://inchoo.net/magento/administration-magento/create-windows-virtual-hosts-for-your-magento-projects/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using virtualhost configurations? This is a very common directory structure. Its super common that we install Magento in a location other than www/html

Refer http://inchoo.net/magento/administration-magento/create-windows-virtual-hosts-for-your-magento-projects/